# How to Update the status then using any field in contact object through process builder?

Tags: process-builder

when i update any filed  record in contact  object then status field need to update using process builder. Please anybody help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status is not a standard field, so I assume you have a custom field called status. I have some screenshots here that describe a very general process builder config to do what you are talking about. You may need to figure out the specifics related to your case.

Click New

---

[image: Click New]

Then click the object box and fill out the details

---

[image: Then click the object box and fill out the details]

Choose the option to run the process when a record is created or edited

---

[image: Choose the option to run the process when a record is created or edited]

You didn't specify any criteria... if you just want it to run on any change don't select a criteria

---

[image: You didn't specify any criteria... if you just want it to run on any change don'd select a criteria]

Choose to update records

---

[image: Choose to update records]

...and select to update the contact that started the process

---

[image: ...and select to update the contact that started the process]

I don't have a status field, but I assume yours is a picklist. Choose the picklist value you want to set, and hit save.

---

[image: I don't have a status field, but I assume yours is a picklist. Choose the picklist value you want to set, and hit save.]

Once you have completed these steps, your process is ready to be activated!